# Using a button click to get results back in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" class="ym-button ym-small" name = "Apply" style="margin-top:1em;max-width:11em" value="Apply" />
</form>

    <?php
if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['Apply'])){
        Apply();

}
}

    function Apply()
    {

$file_handle = fopen("project-list.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts1 = explode("finished", $line_of_text);

echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$parts[0] . $parts[1].'/>";  




}

fclose($file_handle);
    }
?>
```

Why is nothing happening when I press the Apply button? When I have pressed the Apply button I want the results of the function to appear in the Results: `textbox`.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to the below:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" class="ym-button ym-small" name = "Apply" style="margin-top:1em;max-width:11em" value="Apply" />
</form>

    <?php
if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['Apply'])){
        Apply();

}
}

    function Apply()
    {

$file_handle = fopen("project-list.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode("finished", $line_of_text);

echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$parts[0] . $parts[1].'/>";  




}

fclose($file_handle);
    }
?>
```

You had the following code:

```
$parts1 = explode("finished", $line_of_text);
```

instead of:

```
$parts = explode("finished", $line_of_text);
```

You were then accessing an array that didn't exist on this line below:

```
echo "Result:<input type='text' value='$parts[0] . $parts[1].'/>";
```

With the correction you can then access the array as above

Answer (score 3):

Variable name is "parts1", in echo there is "parts". Rename one of the two